# Outlook VBscript method .Send stops scripts

Tags: vbscript, outlook, automationanywhere

I am developing a script to send an email according to certain inputs, I am able to craft the email but not send it using the `.Send` method.

I am getting the following error: (please note that the line is matching the `.Send` use in the original case)

[image]

I have already successfully sent emails using the `.SendKeys(^~)` method, but I would  like to be use Outlook object to do so and not simply send shortcuts.

This is my current code:

```
' Declare all variables that will be used later on
    Dim outobj, mailobj, emailto, cc, subject, body, attachement
    Dim strFileText 
    Dim objFileToRead   
    Dim splitEmailto 

' Set the outlook application object
    Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  

' set the namespace
    Set myNamespace = outobj.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    msgbox myNamespace.Folders(2)

' Set the mail item object
    Set mailobj = outobj.CreateItem(olMailItem) 

' Set a shell
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell")

' Get all the argument and assign
    emailto = "name@domain.eu"
    cc = "name@domain.eu"
    subject = "Simple Email"
    body = "Some Text"
    attachement = "C:\Users\name\Desktop\fileName.xls"

' Craft the email object
    With mailobj

        .Display

        ' assign the tos
        .To = cstr(emailto)

        ' add CCs
        .CC = cstr(cc)

        ' attach the relevant files
        If attachement <> "" Then
            If instr(attachement, ";") Then
                splitAtt = split(attachement, ";")
                For Each att In splitAtt 
                    If att <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.add cstr(att)
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                .Attachments.add cstr(attachement)
            End If
        End If

        If Subject <> "" Then
            .Subject = Subject ' sets the subject   
        End If

        If body <> "" Then
            .Body = body ' sets the body
        End If

        .Send

    End With

' Clear the memory
    Set outobj = Nothing
    Set mailobj = Nothing

' check for no more events in the sending event

' Report out & Quits
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Email sent")
    WScript.Quit
```

I would like to be able to send the email with the `.Send`. any idea?

Comment: Note: I also added the Logon method through NameSpace to make sure I am logged. Didn't change a thing...

Answer (score 0):

The error is `E_ABORT`.
Why are you displaying the message *and* immediately calling Send? You either display the message (Display, but no Send), or just send it outwith displaying (Send, but no Display).

Comment: The `.Display` here is really just for visual testing purposes. But even if I remove the `.Display` and only use `.Send` it does not work and teh same error occurs....

Comment: Does the displayed message look OK with all the recipients and attachments? Does it get sent if you click Send?

Comment: Yes to all, it also gets sent if I `.SendKeys("^~")`

Comment: Maybe quick precision: I am on an Exchange account (just spotted this)

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date AV app on your machine?

Comment: If you mean Anti Virus than probably yes as I am working on an enterprise laptop. Is it blocking certain functions?

Comment: Yes, if an AV app is not installed or if its definitions are out of date, Outlook will start blocking certain functions by either displaying prompts or returning errors.

Comment: Than it’s probably the latter as multinationals are very conservative usually when it comes to using scripts.. alright, thanks!